# How can I log in as a specific user from the meteor shell

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteorite

I am working on an Meteor application.  I have the meteor shell open.  I need to do an insert for a quick test, but I need to pretend that I am authenticated as a particular user (I know the userId).  Inside the meteor shell, is there a way for me to log in as a particular user given the userId?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`meteor shell` gives you access to the server, which is not tied to a particular user session. Instead, you'll want to impersonate users from the client (open the console in your browser).

Try this on the client:

`@impersonateUser = (userId) ->
  Meteor.call "impersonate", userId, (err,res) ->
    if err
      console.log err
    else
      Meteor.connection.setUserId res._id
      console.log 'Now impersonating ' + res.emails[0].address`

And this on the server:

`Meteor.methods
  impersonate: (query) ->
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Permission denied") unless Meteor.user().isAdmin
    u = Meteor.users.findOne(query)
    throw new Meteor.Error(404, "User not found") unless u
    @setUserId u._id
    return u`

And then run `impersonateUser('someUserId')` on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simulate logged in user in meteor shell.

I am not sure what exactly are you testing, but if it is some allow/deny rules on collection, try to create method that do your stuff, log in as wanted user and call method.

Also inside method you can run [`this.setUserId(userId)`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-setUserId). This simply sets the value of userId for future method calls received on this connection.